# How do I create a download pdf button on an HTML form that fills in automatically?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, pdf, pdf-generation

I would like to make a button on the bottom of my summary form that downloads a pdf with all of the inputs and outputs.

The biggest problem is, I'm working in webStorm (which doesn't support php) and I'm somewhat of a noob in web development. Should I download phpStorm and do it there (if so, please give me some suggestions on how to do it), or does anyone have any suggestions just using HTML and JS?

Here is my code currently:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styler.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Calculator</h1>

    <div class="logoPicture-img">
        <img src="images/Logo.png">
    </div>

    <select id="form-selector">
        <option value="_" selected disabled>Pick One</option>
        <option value="Input">Input</option>
        <option value="Output">Output</option>
        <option value="Summary">Summary</option>
    </select>

    <div id="my-forms">
    <form name = "Input">
        <h2>Input</h2>

    <div>
    Cost of Candy ($):
            <br>
            <input type="number" name="costOfCandy" placeholder="5.00" min="0.01" max="20.00">
        </div>
<!-- A bunch more inputs like this follow, but are unshown -->

        <div>
        <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="performCalculations()">
        </div>
    </form>

    <form name = "Output">
        <h2>Output</h2>
        
        <div>
        Baseline Annual Cost of Candy ($):
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="BCostCandy">
        </div>
<!-- A bunch more outputs like this follow, but are unshown -->
    </form>

    <form name = "Summary">
        <h2>Summary</h2>
        <div>
        Impact on Annual Candy Cost ($):
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="NCandyCost">
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>

    <script type = text/javascript>
        const formSelect = document.getElementById('form-selector'),
            myForms = document.getElementById('my-forms');
        formSelect.oninput=()=>{ myForms.className = `f-${formSelect.value}` }
    </script>

    <script type = "text/javascript">
        function performCalculations()
    <!-- Performs all of the calculations and returns them to the appropriate boxes -->
```

Thank you in advance for anyone that can help!

Answer (score 0):

Add the following 2 lines at the end of your file:

```
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- jsPDF library -->
<script src="js/jsPDF/dist/jspdf.min.js"></script>
```

This will ensure that you have some utility in place to get your work done,
the next step is to write out some lines using the jsPDF library.
For example, in your case, if you want the whole body to be a pdf, then,

```
<script>
    var doc = new jsPDF({
    orientation: 'landscape'
    });
    var elementHTML = $('body').html();
    doc.save('document.pdf');
</script>
```

This piece of code added after the above 2 lines should do the magic.

Consult this [article](https://www.codexworld.com/convert-html-to-pdf-using-javascript-jspdf/) for further information:

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use **print.js** library. You can give any area of your web page. If you don't want to export pdf with your current template, you can create appropriate document template and hide it from users and print that one. You can get this library from [here](https://github.com/crabbly/print.js) or from their [site](https://printjs.crabbly.com/).

You can understand it very easily by going through their explanation.